# Where should python pip install?

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am using a raspberry pi 2 board with Raspian. In order to be consistent with my mac I created a separate version of Python v2.7.10. I installed a number of packages that where recommended and I was able to compile it. I placed it in `/usr/local/opt/Python2.7.10`. I then updated my path environment so that this directory comes first. The original Python 2.7.3 is located at `/usr/bin`

Now I need to get pip installed. I downloaded get-pip.py and executed it. pip was installed in `/usr/local/bin`, which is not where either versions of Python exists. This doesn't look right to me. I am not sure if this pip is for the original Python or for the newer version of Python that I created. I just don't want to mix the two. Is this the correct location or do I need to get it somewhere in `/usr/local/opt/`? I am not sure how to get pip to install in `/usr/local/opt/Python2.7.10/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

[pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

To use pip on a specific Python, you need to make sure you have downloaded pip and installed pip for that python version:

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
/path/to/python27 get-pip.py
```

Then use specific pip version to install packages:

```
pip2.7 install somePackage
```